# Proper way to concatenate optional swift strings?

Tags: swift

```
struct Person {
   var firstName: String?
   var lastName: String?
}
```

Now I want to construct a `fullName` string that contains either just their first or last name (if that's all that is available), or if we have both, their first and last name with a space in the middle.

```
var fullName: String?
if let first = person.firstName {
    fullName = first
}
if let last = person.lastName {
    if fullName == nil {
        fullName = last
    } else {
        fullName += " " + last
    }
}
```

or

```
var fullName = ""
if let first = person.firstName {
    fullName = first
}
if let last = person.lastName {
    fullName += fullName.count > 0 ? (" " + last) : last
}
```

Are we just supposed to nest `if let`'s? Nil coalescing seems appropriate but I can't think of how to apply it in this scenario. I can't help but feeling like I'm doing optional string concatenation in an overly complicated way.

Comment: I disagree with @matt here - personally, I think that an empty string is probably a bad representation of no name. What you want the value to represent is "no name", not "a name of `""`".

Answer (score 114, accepted):

`compactMap` would work well here, combined with `.joined(separator:)`:

```
let f: String? = "jo"
let l: String? = "smith"

[f,l] // "jo smith"
  .compactMap { $0 }
  .joined(separator: " ")
```

It doesn't put the space between if one is `nil`:

```
let n: String? = nil

[f,n] // "jo"
  .compactMap { $0 }
  .joined(separator: " ")
```

Comment: And it gives an empty string if both are nil, which is at least sane. Very nice!

Comment: this is the answer i was looking for; thanks! 
by the way, `flatMap` is deprecated, use `compactMap` instead

Answer (score 8):

Somewhere, I believe in the swift book, I ran into this pattern, from when before you could have multiple lets in a single if:

```
class User {
    var lastName : String?
    var firstName : String?

    var fullName : String {
        switch (firstName, lastName) {
        case (.Some, .Some):
            return firstName! + " " + lastName!

        case (.None, .Some):
            return lastName!

        case (.Some, .None):
            return firstName!

        default:
            return ""
        }
    }

    init(lastName:String?, firstName:String?) {
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.firstName = firstName
    }
}

User(lastName: nil, firstName: "first").fullName        // -> "first"
User(lastName: "last", firstName: nil).fullName         // -> "last"
User(lastName: nil, firstName: nil).fullName            // -> ""
User(lastName: "last", firstName: "first").fullName     // -> "first last"
```

An even briefer solution, given swift 3.0:

```
var fullName : String {
    return [ firstName, lastName ].flatMap({$0}).joined(separator:" ")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes simple is best:

```
let first = p.first ?? ""
let last = p.last ?? ""
let both = !first.isEmpty && !last.isEmpty
let full = first + (both ? " " : "") + last
```

This works if there is no `first` or `last`, if there is a `first` but no `last`, if there is a `last` but no `first`, and if there are both a `first` and a `last`. I can't think of any other cases.

Here's an idiomatic incorporation of that idea into a calculated variable; as an extra benefit, I've allowed `full` to be `nil` just in case both the other names are `nil`:

```
struct Person {
    var first : String?
    var last : String?
    var full : String? {
        if first == nil && last == nil { return nil }
        let fi = p.first ?? ""
        let la = p.last ?? ""
        let both = !fi.isEmpty && !la.isEmpty
        return fi + (both ? " " : "") + la
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the usage of the nil coalescing operator here. Thank you for the concise example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative method:

```
let name = 
(person.first != nil && person.last != nil) ? 
person.first! + " " + person.last! : 
person.first ?? person.last!
```

Comment: Succinct solution, however, I believe the last part needs to be unwrapped like `person.last!`.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are want to check `nil` and `""` value as well you can do something like this:

```
var a: String? = nil
let b = "first value"
let c: String? = nil
let d = ""
let e = "second value"
var result = [a,b,c,d,e].compactMap{ $0 }.filter { $0 != "" }.joined(separator:", ")
print(result)
//first value, second value
```

Answer (score 1):

I like [oisdk's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33905852/3965) but I didn't like the empty string if both were `nil`.  I would rather have `nil`.

```
func add(a a: String?, b: String?, separator: String = " ") -> String? {
    let results = [a, b].flatMap {$0}
    guard results.count > 0 else { return nil }
    return results.joinWithSeparator(separator)
}
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that rather than having two strings as your arguments, you could leave it as an array of optional strings, allowing you to concatenate an arbitrary number of optional strings.

Answer (score 1):

What oisdk answered was great, but I needed something very specific along the lines of the OP's original question.

Writing for **Swift 4.x**, I created this extension which works well when populating other strings, such as text labels. I have also updated it to include a function for handling an array if needed.

```
extension String {
    static func combine(first: String?, second: String?) -> String {
        return [first, second].compactMap{ $0 }.joined(separator: " ")
    }

    static func combine(strings: [String?]) -> String {
        return strings.compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}
```

An example of this populating a text label with two optional strings:

```
print(String.combine(first: "First", second: "Last")) // "First Last"
print(String.combine(first: "First", second: nil)) // "First"
print(String.combine(first: nil, second: "Last")) // "Last"
```

If you have an array of optional strings, you can call the array function:

```
print(String.combine(strings: ["I", "Have", nil, "A", "String", nil, "Here"])) 
// "I Have A String Here"
```

Comment: Flawless way to add two optional strings. +1

Comment: Thanks @SatnamSync, I updated the question for Swift 4.x & added the ability to also process arrays as well.

Answer (score 1):

for swift 4

```
let name: String? = "Foo"
let surname: String? = "Bar"

let fullname = (name ?? "") + " " + (surname ?? "")

print(fullname)
// Foo Bar
```

Comment: Beside the code, you should also provide a description of the solution you're proposing.

Comment: and? In some cases you get extra space symbol

Answer (score 0):

```
func getSingleValue(_ value: String?..., seperator: String = " ") -> String? {

    return value.reduce("") {
    ($0) + seperator + ($1 ?? "")
    }.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: seperator) )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's too bad that there isn't more support for operators on the `Optional` enum, but I overloaded the standard concatenation operator (`+`) like this:

```
func +<T: StringProtocol>(lhs: Optional<T>, rhs: Optional<T>) -> String {
    return [lhs, rhs].compactMap({ $0 }).joined()
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
let first: String? = "first"
let last: String? = nil

first + first // "firstfirst"
first + last // "first"
last + first // "first"
last + last // ""
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add-On:**

Consider you have Struct:

```
struct Person {
   var firstName: String?
   var lastName: String?
}
```

you can use the *CustomStringConvertible*

```
extension Person: CustomStringConvertible {

var description: String {
        [firstName, lastName].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}

 let person1 = Person(firstName "Jeba", lastName: "Moses")
 print(person1) // Prints "Jeba Moses"

let person2 = Person(firstName: "Ebenrick", lastName: nil)
print(person2) // Prints "Ebenrick"
```